# Assignment operator of std::variant of custom type with deleted special member functions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, assignment-operator, std-variant

Consider:

```
#include <variant>

struct A { 
  A() = default;
  A(A&&) = delete;
};

struct B { 
  B() = delete;
  B(A&&) {};
};

int main() {
  std::variant<A, B> v{};
  v = A{};
}
```

MSVC accepted it, [while GCC and Clang rejected it with the same error message](https://godbolt.org/z/3Ef7Ebddr):

```
opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.0.0/../../../../include/c++/12.0.0/variant:1465:3: error: call to deleted member function 'operator='
                operator=(variant(std::forward<_Tp>(__rhs)));
                ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:15:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::variant<A, B>::operator=<A>' requested here
  v = A{};
    ^
```

Which compiler should I trust?

Comment: Did you check std::monostate? It may be suitable for this kind of situations.

Comment: It seems that according to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator%3D) (converting assignment part), `T_j` should be resolved as `B`: https://godbolt.org/z/nqhxxjPM1.

Comment: @Daniel Langr. That's right, according to [variant#assign-11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/variant#assign-11), we seem [should](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/variant#assign-13.3) use `operator=(variant(std​::​forward<T>(t)))` to initialize `B`, but I'm not sure we should just perform [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) in such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Initially, there was no `language-lawyer` tag, which was why I used *cppreference* for the analysis. However, looking into the latest draft ([relevant section](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant#lib:operator=,variant__)), I don't see anything that would make it invalid.

---

I believe MSVC is incorrect. According to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator%3D):

> 3. Converting assignment.
>
> - Determines the alternative type `T_j` that would be selected by overload resolution for the expression `F(std::forward<T>(t))` if there was an overload of imaginary function `F(T_i)` for every `T_i` from `Types...` in scope at the same time, except that:
>
>   - An overload `F(T_i)` **is only considered if the declaration `T_i x[] = { std::forward<T>(t) };` is valid** for some invented variable `x`;

With some imaginary function having forwarding reference parameter and calling it with `A{}` argument, `A x[] = { std::forward<T>(t) };` is not valid while `B x[] = { std::forward<T>(t) };` is. Consequently , `T_j` should be resolved as `B`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/fM67e7oGj.

Then:

> - If `*this` already holds a `T_j`...

This does not apply, since `v` does not hold a `B`.

Next:

> - Otherwise, if `std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T_j, T> || !std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T_j>` is `true`...

This also does not apply, since this expression is `false`; live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/x674rnbcj (and, MSVC agrees on that: https://godbolt.org/z/5Techn8jG).

Finally:

> - Otherwise, equivalent to `this->operator=(variant(std::forward<T>(t)))`.

However, this call does not compile with MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/cWr4f6EhK.

Comment: Same as I thought, but the MSVC-STL contributor thought it [should](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/2171) be accepted in this case, so I added the tag of `language lawyer`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 The analysis seems to apply also to the latest draft — [relevant section](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant#lib:operator=,variant__). I can't see anything that would disagree with _cppreference_.